# How to selectively print portions of a list in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

So I have a csv full of drink data

> Drink,ABV,Type Gin,45,Spirit Prosecco,11,Wine Vodka,40,Spirit
>   Absinthe,70,Spirit Sherry,20,Wine Stout,8,Beer Lager,4,Beer
>   Ouzo,37,Spirit

Here is my JS and I want it to go through the array and check for spirits, then print out the spirits in the console.

```
var spirit_list = [];

function drink(a,b,c) {
    this.Drink = a;
    this.ABV = b;
    this.Type = c;

}

d3.csv("alcohol.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d){
        myDrink = new drink(); // new drink object
        if (d.Type === "Spirit"){ //logic to grab spirits
            myDrink.name = d.Drink; // assign obj values
            myDrink.abv = +d.ABV;
            spirit_list.push(myDrink) // push the obj to a list
        };
    console.log(spirit_list);
       // d.abv = +d.ABV; // + : converts into a number, instead of the default string
    })
    // console.log(data); // data becomes sucked into console.log and becomes an array
    // fyi everything is parsed into strings (from the spreadsheet .csv to the log)
});

}
```

But I only want the name and ABV to show up, I do not want all the other object property (drink, abv, and type to show up as undefined)

> Console Log output: 0: Object { Drink: undefined, name: "Gin", abv: 45, … }

Is it possible?

Comment: well you would need to delete it. If the method has a,b,c defined, why are you not just passing them in when you call it?

Comment: This was a tutorial scenario set up by my TA. I agree on your point but somehow she (or cheated/omitted the undefined in her screenshot) removed the undefined properties. Could I fix this simply by hot fixing it by passing in empty strings for the properties? But none the less, the field would then show up yeah?

Comment: Than do not define Drink when it is created.

Comment: It seems a little unclear what exactly you're trying to log. Does it have to be the entire object? Why not just do: console.log(myDrink.name, myDrink.abv);

Comment: But @epascarello, how would I then parse through the spreadsheet data? Say down the road I am working with a spread sheet for a liquor store. So I have tons of data. And then I just want to find Spirits only. Well upon parsing I would grab all the object properties. But then on filtering I need only certain data. So there is no way to avoid this other than making a brand new function, say function drink (name,abv) {....}. ? I'm learning JS on the fly, this is for a course to visualize data so that is why I'm worried for selection purposes/display/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `drink` function, this is good, it's a simple 'class' you can use later on to create a list of multiple drinks.

```
function drink(a,b,c) {
    this.Drink = a;
    this.ABV = b;
    this.Type = c;

}
```

The three properties you've defined on `drink` are what you should be using when you create each `myDrink` object. Change your creation code like so...move the drink creation inside the `if` statement and only add the properties you want. If you have properties you don't need to use in this instance, just `delete` them:

```
if (d.Type === "Spirit"){ //logic to grab spirits
  myDrink = new drink(d.Drink, d.ABV, d.Type); // new drink object
  delete myDrink['Type'];
  spirit_list.push(myDrink) // push the obj to a list
};
```

Here's a complete example:

```js
var spirit_list = [];

function drink(a,b,c) {
    this.Drink = a;
    this.ABV = b;
    this.Type = c;

}

getData().forEach(function(d){
    myDrink = new drink(); // new drink object
    if (d.Type === "Spirit"){ //logic to grab spirits
      myDrink = new drink(d.Drink, d.ABV, d.Type);
      delete myDrink['Type'];
      spirit_list.push(myDrink) // push the obj to a list
    };
   // d.abv = +d.ABV; // + : converts into a number, instead of the default string
});

console.log(spirit_list);
// console.log(data); // data becomes sucked into console.log and becomes an array
// fyi everything is parsed into strings (from the spreadsheet .csv to the log)

function getData() {
  return [
 {
   "Drink": "Gin",
   "ABV": 45,
   "Type": "Spirit"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Prosecco",
   "ABV": 11,
   "Type": "Wine"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Vodka",
   "ABV": 40,
   "Type": "Spirit"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Absinthe",
   "ABV": 70,
   "Type": "Spirit"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Sherry",
   "ABV": 20,
   "Type": "Wine"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Stout",
   "ABV": 8,
   "Type": "Beer"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Lager",
   "ABV": 4,
   "Type": "Beer"
 },
 {
   "Drink": "Ouzo",
   "ABV": 37,
   "Type": "Spirit"
 }
];
}
```